Nginx vhost logging not working as expected
I am trying to set up a fairly simple vhost configuration using nginx (1.22) on Debian 12 VPS. Apart from default nginx configuration, I've created a very basic vhost file mydomain.com.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    root /var/www/mydomain.com/html;
    index index.html

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-error.log error;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

The domain is registered with Cloudflare and points to the VPS (both IPv4 and IPv6). Just to eliminate any other factors, they are not proxied by Cloudflare.
The expectation is:

When VPS is accessed by IP, default configuration is used (and logging goes to the default log)
When mydomain.com is accessed, the vhost configuration kicks in with files served from /var/www/mydomain.com/html and logging going into /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-*.log

However instead, I observe something very different and confusing when accessing mydomain.com:

Files are served from /var/www/mydomain.com/html (as expected)
Access requests are logged in the default access log, not in the vhost-specific one.
Vhost-specific error log is created but stays empty. It is also created owned by root:root rather than www-data (as the default logs).
No vhost-specific access log is created but stays empty.

Could anyone please help me understand if there's something I might be missing in the configuration?

Remove the criticity at the end of your error_log directive. Maybe this is why your error log stays empty. And dont forget to reload nginx: systemctl restart nginx. Also, what are the exact UNIX permissions on your log files ?

Tried to completely purge nginx and reinstall afresh just in case - same effect. Same applies to removing the 'error' level from the vhost error_log. As far as permissions go, main logs are www-data:adm mode 0640 whereas the vhost error log is root:root mode 0644.

The problem was due to the missing semicolon at the preceding directive. I am not sure why I didn't see this before (and I was looking) but after a couple of restarts and trial-and-error attempts, I spotted the following warning:
[warn] ... only the last index in "index" directive should be absolute in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf:9

The directive preceding access_log was index and it lacked a semicolon. So, stupid me, of course but no brownie points to nginx for being so permissive with the syntax.
